# domain object sharing microservices

Tags: java, database-design, architecture, microservices, spring-cloud

I am trying to understand Microservices. I would like to know how to tackle the problem of one to many/ many to many relationship in microservices architecture and what's the best practice. Assume I want to convert student-course app to student service and course service and student service talks to Student table and course service talks Course table in the same database.

Example:
Students can enroll to many courses and also many courses can have many students( Many to Many relationship). I have 2 microservices
Microservices 1: Student-service
Microservices 2: Course-service

**Student Service has Student object**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
public class Student {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;


//@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
//@JoinTable(name = "STUDENT_COURSE", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = //"STUDENT_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "COURSE_ID"))
//  private List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<Course>();
}
```

**Course Service has Course object**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COURSE")
public class Course {

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
private long id;

@Column(name = "COURSE_NAME")
private String name;

//@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courses", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
//private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
}
```

I understand student services has to make call to course service to get the courses but how do I map course to a student?( like student A has enrolled to Course X,Y,Z)

- How do I get list of courses for a student or list of students for a
  course?
- Do I need to duplicate **Course** class in **Student
  Service** and **Student** class in **Course service**?
- Do I need to
  move the domain classes to common project and then share between
  microservices to avoid duplicating?

Can you please help me by answering the best practice to solve many to many relationship problem in microservice?

Comment: Do your microservices raise any events?

Comment: not as of now, this has to be implemented. I welcome your suggestions

Answer (score 2):

When thinking about microservices, it helps to remember the concepts of [Bounded contexts](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html)

> *Martin Fowler* : **Bounded Contexts** have both unrelated concepts (such as a support ticket only existing in a customer support context) but also *share concepts* (such as products and customers). *Different contexts may have completely different models of common concepts* with mechanisms to map between these polysemic concepts for integration.

The concepts of Student and Course can be very different in each microservice of your application. For example, a Student can be defined as a person with an identifier, a first name, a last name, and an address in the StudentInformationManagement microservice, and have only an identifier, and a list of courses in the CourseAttendance microservice.

That is to say I wouldn't use a shared database for these microservices, instead I would create separate databases with the needed entities. Only the identifier is "shared" between the services.

Try thinking about your process when designing your data models : which information do I get when a student registers ? Which when he enrolls in a class ?

Comment: I'm used to create different databases for different environments (development, homologation, production, D-1, etc.), and for each context I call specific owners and namespaces.

Comment: Great reference. Just my 2 cents, I find that once you get over the fact that you're duplicating code (it hurts us all), you'll find that encapsulating your services actually helps make things more robust. For example, I have many "duplicated" classes throughout my services, but the "borrowed" classes typically have fewer fields and they only have getters (don't let a borrowing service modify another service's entity). The reason this is great is it ensures these objects are immutable outside of their own context.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical gotcha in the world of microservices. Even in micro service oriented architectures, the focus should be on the solving very specific business problems and then have supporting database tables.

It seems that a 'StudentRegistration' service might help in this case, which can get hold of the joins in question. Having a third service like 'StudentRegistration' might introduce more than obvious network calls within the services, if caching is used properly, these microservices could respond very fast.

Infact, then you could evaluate that whether you need all three services at the end, i.e. Student, Course and StudentRegistration OR some combination(s) can be merged, as per your business-processes or use-cases. That can be done if a combination of some of them are not able to answer most of the business questions without knowing about each other.

Finally, it might not be completely wrong to actually implement microservices over a shared DB. See: http://microservices.io/patterns/data/shared-database.html

Please note that having totally separate databases for such closely related microservices and keeping those tables in sync all the time, through eventing model is not straightforward, so be careful there. It is not impossible, however. There are documented design patterns to cater to business transactions spanning multiple microservices, namely: CQRS pattern (https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html), SAGA pattern(http://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html) and Event sourcing: http://microservices.io/patterns/data/event-sourcing.html.

Comment: so if I am using shared database, do I need duplicate the Course domain object in Student Service Student object and Student domain object in Course Service Course class? How do we do that? Do I need to use @Entity of domain objects in both the services ?

Comment: Hibernate creates tables for me, so what domain objects should be present and how should the domain object look in course service and student service?